# Zend Mail - Pdf Attachment - imbedded png gets scrambled

Tags: zend-framework, pdf, png, email-attachments, zend-mail

I've got my Zend_Mail setup and working fine, but the png images in my pdf attachment get scrambled.

This is the bit responsible for the attachment:

```
$filecontents = file_get_contents($attachment);

$att = $this->mail->createAttachment($filecontents);
$att->disposition = 'Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_INLINE';
$att->encoding = 'Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64';
$att->filename = 'result.pdf';
$att->type = 'application/pdf';
```

The Pdf is created with Zend_Pdf

The PNG is added like this:

```
$image = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath("path/to/png.png");
$this->page->drawImage($image, $left, $bottom, $right, $top);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you actually want the PDF to be inline in the email?  I don't think email clients even support that.  Try Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT.

Also, the constants should not be in quotes.  It's just $at->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHEMENT.

Comment: Thanks, totaly overlooked the quotes :s

Answer (score 0):

Why do you set inline disposition for a PDF attachment? The mail client can't display it inline anyway (unlike the GIF in the Zend example).

The PNG format contains a \r\n in its signature, so I'd check for corruption there.. possibly triggered by the disposition:INLINE setting, but perhaps you've enabled some stream wrappers you're not telling us about?